# Inheritance in ViewModel Design on MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, mvvm

I am little confuse on the ViewModel design with Inheritance.

Scenaro:

I have a datamodel and multiple viewmodels of User Enity. I am using ADO.Net to fetch from DB bind to  datamodel. And the datamodel can be passed to different ViewModel.It seems Ok with one or two views. But When number of my Views increases, I need different ViewModels. Also I want to avoid redundant fields in my ViewModel. And I create a UserBaseModel. So all ViewModel inherit from it

Problem:

I have password and confirm password fields for UserSetting Views and UserRegistration view and I create UserSettingViewModel and UserRegistrationViewModel. And I dont think other viewmodel do not require this fields. I dont want to define the fields in UserBaseModel and also I dont want to define multiple times for the same fields in both ViewModels.

Is there any alternative? Suggestions and advices  are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little more thoughts give me another solution.

```
  public PasswordModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}

public UserSettingViewModel
{
    public PasswordModel Password { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C# doesn't support [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) you can't derive the models from a second base model. You basically end up with creating another base view model which derives from `UserBaseModel` and contain the password properties:

```
public UserBaseModelWithPassword : UserBaseModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can derive `UserSettingViewModel` and `UserRegistrationViewModel` from it.

Comment: Multilevel inheritance. This seems an alternative. But would not my View model classes got quite complicated when there are also other fields that has to be shared in some views and not to shared with others?

Comment: @MillerKoijam if you don't need the fields in _all_ your views, then you should not add them to the base view model, or not derive from the base view model. I don't really see the problem.

Comment: But my concern is for those fields which cannot be defined in baseModel but has to share with some views (like password), But that was an example. I have more field like passwords.

Comment: @MillerKoijam I think there is no other option then creating new base view models for all the view models that have common properties. It's either that, or duplicating properties across view models. I think I'll go with the first since that is the strength of OOP.

Comment: I think I got another option. see my answer